# how to tune out of memory exception spark

Tags: performance, hadoop, apache-spark, cluster-computing

i have 11 nodes, each one has 2G of memory and 16 cores, i try to submit my spark application using this

```
./bin/spark-submit --class myapp.Main --master spark://Name:7077 --conf spark.shuffle.memoryFraction=0 --executor-memory 2G --deploy-mode client /home/mbala/fer/myjars7/etlpersist.jar /home/mfile80.csv
```

in Slaves file i didn't add the node's ip in wich i launch this command because i think that in Client mode the driver must be running in this node.

but whenever i try to run it, i get out of memory exception (sometimes because of GC or because of the Heap),i tried many solutions suggested in spark website and also here in stackOverflow, i also tried to minimize my code, i used MemoryAndDiskStorage but even that i still have this problem

Ps: i use this line because i found it as solution in this forum

--conf spark.shuffle.memoryFraction=0

> should i minimize the number of cores? because i think that if i use 16 cores with only 2G memory it won't be enough for shuffle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try to use the small **`g`** with **`--executor-memory`** and **`--driver-memory`** options in command that will help you.

When you set the executor memory to **`2GB`**. Then it only assigns **`0.6%`** of the original memory for storage and execution and it takes **`0.5%`** as storage memory from the **`0.6%`** of original memory. Hence only **`0.5%`** of memory remains available for execution.

You should understand this concept of [memory management](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#memory-management). It will help you in debugging the application.

Comment: i still have it when i try with input files over than 1G

Comment: I have added details regarding the memory management configuration. Please go through it.

Comment: @asma, Did you get any breakthrough?